# Barcode using Java head less mode configuration

Tags: java, jfreechart, barcode, xserver

In an application, for every order confirmation from customer side, an order confirmation mail is being sent to the customer.
So in that mail a barcode will be provided (barcode image and a barcode number under the image - as usual).
The following packages are used to achieve this.
org.krysalis.barcode4j.*, org.apache.avalon.*, javax.xml.transform.*

The problem is, X-vnc server(a port basically don't have much idea about this part) is what being used and it need to be removed due to some security reasons.

So the suggestions are to introduce JFreeChart or to Make use of java’s headless mode configuration.
Can somebody tell me how I can make use of java’s headless mode configuration for generating barcodes as JFreeChart is out of question from my investigation.

Note:- Barcode image is generated based on the order number. As order numbers are unique, the barcode images generated will also be unique.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the reply!

Application server which runs on Linux uses XVNC (Virtual screen based on X server) to act as virtual display. This is to support JVM to create barcode images.

So two things need to be achieved.

1. Remove the xvnc dependency.
2. Find an alternative for rendering the barcode image (headless mode may be not sure about this, so suggestions please  - Xvfb is not permitted though.

Note:- I could see a .Xauthority file of which I couldn't see the content, I am unable to open it. Any idea what this file will contain?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In the article from Oracle you can find information about headless mode and how to convert an existing application to headless mode. It's a little bit old but it should work

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html

Comment: More [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1012&hilit=X11%20DISPLAY%20BufferedImage).